# Windows Phone SQL Server CE Local database explorer

Tags: windows-phone, sql-server-ce

I am working on a Windows Phone 8 app using SQL Server CE as a local database. Do anyone has an idea of a tool or a way to explore, browse or query the data within the database on the phone or emulator, for debugging purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must copy the database file to your local disk, and open it with a desktop Tool, like for example my SQL Server Toolbox